# how to hide a vb app in task manager apps list

Tags: vb.net, taskmanager

I want to hide vb app name in task manager apps list, but it can be visible in background process
can anyone give a example using me.hide() or any other methods

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no practical use for this. If you want something to run in the background, write a windows service

Comment: You want an example using `Me.Hide()`? Ok, here you go: `Me.Hide()`.

Comment: If you have a winforms application but you don't use the forms, you can uncheck the `Enable Application Framework` checkbox in the Project Properties. Then you just create a Module and a method where you place your code. Set the Startup Object to that method and now you have a background application which can still interact with the user's desktop.